# Does Heidegger treat the word "life"?

Tags: reference-request, heidegger, life

I would like to know if there are some references in which heidegger treats the word life.
What does Heidegger say about life, and where?

Comment: Isn't Heidegger's whole book "Being and Time" with its core concept of "Dasein" about human life?

Comment: The question is not for human life, it is for the word life.

Comment: Your question is pretty general. Heidegger's idiosyncratic terminology doesn't employ "life" in any significant way, as far as I know, though he may have picked up lebenswelt from Husserl.  Perhaps you could word-search a PDF or online version of SZ. Evidently he discusses biology in 1929-30 lectures, disputing Darwin, teleology, and the whole idea of mechanistic "sciences of life." Perhaps you would do better to search for references to "animals" within the schema of beings.

Comment: There is *[lebenswelt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifeworld)* (life-world), but this is Husserlian; Heidegger was a student of Husserl, so there may be a connection there.

Answer (score 1):

Heidegger uses the word Life (*Leben*) all over the place (it appears at least once in every volume of the GA), as do most of us, but the word itself doesn't appear to have a special place in his terminology. In places he refers to other philosophers' use of the word (Aristotle, Hegel). He looks at some related etymology; e.g., *Er-Leben*.